# How can Windows Runtime Component written in C++ be referenced from Class Library written in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, windows-phone-8, class-library

I am working on WP8 project that includes class library project as C# source code and Windows Runtime Component as C++ source code. Does anyone know whether or not it is possible to create such C# class library which would reference Windows Runtime Component? The ultimate result should be .NET assembly and .WIMND/.DLL runtime component that can be used for application. Currently I cannot build class library because it doesn't see Windows Runtime Component, even though I added it to the project.

More specific. I have, say, MyNs.MyClass.MyMethod() which is defined in C++ runtime component and used from C# class library. Currently I cannot compile C# due to missing method although I have windows runtime component project attached to the same solution.

Comment: Project + Add References, Solution node, tick your C++ project.

Comment: Class Library or Portable Class Library? And if the latter, what targets did you choose?

Comment: I selected Class Library (Windows Phone 8.0). Anyway I solved this by manually adding reference to .winmd file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding reference to Windows runtime component manually into the C# class library .csproj file as follows

```
...
    <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="WindowsRuntimeComponent.winmd" />
    </ItemGroup>
...
```

Comment: Where was the `.winmd` file relative to the `.csproj`? Was this the only step, or was it in addition to adding the `.winmd` into the references section?

Comment: Windows Runtime Component consists from two parts - native DLL and the wrapper WINMD code that maps the native part to managed interfaces. For compiling only it is enough to place WINMD into the same folder where C# class library DLL is. For proper functioning all thee component shall be present at same folder - C# class library DLL, C++/CX WINMD managed part and C++/CX native DLL.

Comment: Some clarifications on the previous comment: .winmd files do not contain any (wrapper) code. They contain meta-data only, re-using .NET's file format. The compiler uses the meta-data to emit code to access the Windows Runtime component.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am butting in because this is not my area, I tried Googling for "c# call windows runtime component".  There seem to be many hits/examples, e.g. the first one is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh755833.aspx.

Does that not help you?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Most of those examples explain how to call component from the App. In my case it is not an app, it is a class library that needs to be delivered as .NET assembly DLL.

Comment: Understood, sorry it didn't help.  Given that, perhaps you might add "class library" or similar to this question's tags?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make a C++ WRL project and use a class in that project from a C# project by adding a reference in the normal way. The Wrl project (not C++/CX, which also works) was made using some WRL template that I found somewhere on the web. The wrl project required me to make a .idl to define the interface, and produced its .dll and .winmd. Here is some code for those who are battling with this type of thing:

The Wrl class:

```
#include "pch.h"

#include "WrlTestClass2_h.h"
#include <wrl.h>

using namespace Microsoft::WRL;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;

namespace ABI
{
    namespace WrlTestClass2
    {
        class WinRTClass: public RuntimeClass<IWinRTClass>
        {
            InspectableClass(RuntimeClass_WrlTestClass2_WinRTClass, BaseTrust)

            public:
            WinRTClass()
            {
            }

            // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155856.aspx
            // Walkthrough: Creating a Basic Windows Runtime Component Using WRL
            HRESULT __stdcall Add(_In_ int a, _In_ int b, _Out_ int* value)
            {
                if (value == nullptr)
                {
                    return E_POINTER;
                }
                *value = a + b;
                return S_OK;
            }

        };

        ActivatableClass(WinRTClass);
    }
}
```

The C# code that uses this class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.UnitTestFramework;


namespace CSharpClientToWrl
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            WrlTestClass2.WinRTClass _winRtTestClass = new WrlTestClass2.WinRTClass();

            int _answer = _winRtTestClass.Add(4, 6);

            Assert.AreEqual(_answer, 10);
        }
    }
}
```

The .idl file of the wrl project:

```
import "inspectable.idl"; import "Windows.Foundation.idl";

#define COMPONENT_VERSION 1.0

namespace WrlTestClass2 {
    interface IWinRTClass;
    runtimeclass WinRTClass;

    [uuid(0be9429f-2c7a-40e8-bb0a-85bcb1749367), version(COMPONENT_VERSION)] 
    interface IWinRTClass : IInspectable
    {       // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155856.aspx        // Walkthrough: Creating a Basic Windows Runtime Component Using WRL        HRESULT Add([in] int a, [in] int b, [out, retval] int* value);
    }

    [version(COMPONENT_VERSION), activatable(COMPONENT_VERSION)]
    runtimeclass WinRTClass
    {
        [default] interface IWinRTClass;
    } }
```